# Learning as an adult: After the end of your formal education and before you get a job?

Tags: motivation, independent-study

I'm a recent CS graduate. I realize the value of going to college and getting a degree now. It'd be absolutely impossible to learn everything taught in college on my own looking at my current situation.

**I'm studying to get a job currently as well as to pass licensing exam for engineering graduates in  my country. But main focus is job.**

I'm also studying subjects like DBMS, Operating System, Data Structures and Algorithms because they too are somewhat related to web development/programming and studying just 1 subject per day is very bad thing if you get stuck. My goal is to rotate between 3 things per day, Web development, DBMS and DSA/OS. I've to say that I'm re-learning these subjects. I've already studied them in college but I didn't studied them well at that time as they were taught when I was freshman in college.

Companies here (It's Nepal) Don't like training new grads so generally you're all on your own. I need to upskill myself to a point where I can get guidance but don't need that guidance.

Here are the problems I'm facing atm.

1. I"m not sure what topics should I learn? For eg: If I had to learn DSA in college, I'd just learn the syllabus/contents that the college gave to us. Do I still do the same?
2. I'm not sure what should I practice. What exercises. A book has 100s of exercises in 1 chapter and it's obvious, nobody can afford to solve each of them. In uni, I'd either solve "assignments" or "previous year question papers" and learn a lot from them. For each chapter(eg: memory mgmt,process mgmt are 2 chapters of OS), I'd be doing 20 long+short questions. What do I do now?
3. I've no natural/real deadline. No pressure of exams. That is really harmful as I won't be finishing anything in time like this. I'm always in a hurry. I'm scared of wasting more time. I am impatient because there's nobody to fix deadlines for me. There's nobody to tell me how much time something will require to me. I've never took an year loss in my entire life.
4. I'm facing failures after failures  in learning when starting to learn from a gap(I took around 2 weeks gap).
5. Staying at home all day is mentally tough and draining. I'm always unfocused. Mind is wandering here and there. I'm not sure the science behind that, but it's really creating cluttered and useless mind. "Empty mind, devil's home". There are no "IT Training Institutes" that are worth the money here in my state even though it's the state with capital city.

No public libraries that allow "work space with laptop and books" has been a huge issue. Recently, I've heard ihub allows it so I'm optimistic.

Luckily, I'm not really sad about being away from uni and amn't demotivated by it. I need guidance to move forward more than anything else. This is a huge change of scenario for me. It has been around 1 month of it and I'm still like this. It's true that I've not have to study for whole 1 month because I'd other things to do, so I was in a break from studying. I'm seeking for non-medical guidance here.

Some suggestions given to me by my friends is to "learn bare minimum and get a job", but that's  a catch-22. Learning bare minimum is what I'm trying to do. Make project, learn dsa for interviews. That's all. Learning a lot isn't a problem for me atm(ofc it is), but learning anything(even just 1 thing) is a problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You have too many questions. Please, ask 1 question for each post. Also, your questions are out of the scope of the community.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really stuck, the world is full of options and you do not know which one you have to pick and you do not know what the different companies are *really* doing , look for an internship.

You will get a bit of life inside a company and you will be able to focus on what you want to do, what you can do and more importantly **what they need**.

Working for a company is not related to what you want. A company is simply buying your work to sell it for a profit ... so your task is now to find a reasonable match between what you can deliver and what a certain company is needing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my advises that could help:

1. You should spend some time for searching what you want exactly, and since your goal is to get a job, then it is necessary to check the job offers and know their requirements in order to learn them.
2. **Make a roadmap for learning the required skills**, and set a duration for each step, set goals and follow a rewarding system (if you learn/accomplish something, reward yourself).
3. **Focus on one thing per time**, learning many modules can make you distracted.
4. Create a group of serious friends to learn together and share knowledge.
5. Github is a treasure, you can check others' source codes and learn from them, as well as you can share your programs and get back comments. In general, working within a team can improve your skills.

Good luck